# Sitecore Repeatedly Committing

Tags: sitecore

In my log files I am seeing the following entries:

```
ManagedPoolThread #0 11:19:00 DEBUG Committing table: Status
ManagedPoolThread #0 11:19:00 DEBUG Row# 693badb3-51a0-7ea0-4617-824aedfb7d6f Modified
ManagedPoolThread #0 11:19:00 DEBUG Trying 1 by 1 update...
ManagedPoolThread #0 11:19:00 DEBUG Commit success.
```

This log message is being constantly repeated as soon as the site starts every 12 seconds.

Anyone know the source of this problem?

Comment: What version of sitecore was this? Did you ever get to a solution? @Michael-Edwards

Answer (score 0):

Frequent committing to the Status table is expected behavior. 
You can disable the DEBUG logging level (ERROR > WARN > INFO > DEBUG) using the following setting in the web.config file:

```
<log4net>
...
  <root>
    <priority value="WARN" />
  </root>
...
</log4net>
```

Change the value to needed logging level.